# How to determine dragged outlook mailObject attachment

Tags: vba, outlook, drag-and-drop, treeview, email-attachments

I have a `userform` with a treeview control `MSComctlLib.TreeView`. It is used to save files that are dragged on top of it to the drive. My problem is that whenever an email has multiple attachment and one is dragged over, there is no apparent way to tell which one specific attachment out of multiple is selected.

Code below includes an event fired when the file is dragged to the `TreeView` and then calls a sub based on the `DataObject` format. When the attachment is dragged, this code parses all of the attachments in the currently selected email (after filtering out embedded images). The ordering of `attachments` does not change based on which attachment is selected and I could not find a `PropertyAccessor` property that may be helpful.

```
Private Sub treeView_OLEDragDrop(Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
    Select Case True
        Case Data.GetFormat(13): 'process Email
        Case Data.GetFormat(15): 'process files
        Case Else: processAttachments
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub processAttachments()
    Dim outlookApp As Object: Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim selection As Object: Set selection = outlookApp.activeexplorer.selection
    Dim email As Object
    Dim attachment As Object
    For Each email In selection
        For Each attachment In email.Attachments
            If Not attachment.PropertyAccessor. _
                GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37140003") = 4 _
                                        Then ' filters out embedded images
                Debug.Print attachment.DisplayName
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Is there a method to determine which one of the email attachments is currently selected or is currently being dragged over?

Answer (score 1):

The best what you could do is to track the currently selected attachment in Outlook, so if the drag and drop operation is made you could quickly get the currently selected attachment. Or just use the `AttachmentSelection` property as explained below to get the selected attachments in Outlook.

- The [Explorer.AttachmentSelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.attachmentselectionchange?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm3483)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) event is fired when the user selects a different or additional attachment in the active explorer programmatically or by interacting with the user interface.
- The [Inspector.AttachmentSelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.attachmentselectionchange?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm3484)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) event is fired when the user selects a different or additional attachment of an item in the active inspector programmatically or by interacting with the user interface.

To get the selected attachments you need to use the [Explorer.AttachmentSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.attachmentselection?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm3479)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) or [Inspector.AttachmentSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.attachmentselection?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm3486)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) property which returns an `AttachmentSelection` object consisting of one or more attachments that are selected in the explorer or inspector respectively.

The `AttachmentSelection` object contains a read-only collection of attachments that are selected in an item that is in the active inspector or the active explorer.

Comment: This is helpful. However `ActiveExplorer.AttachmentSelection.Count` returns zero if I start dragging the attachment before clicking it first - it returns the attachment correctly if it is clicked first, the dragged. Attachment preview is turned on if it matters. Do you have any workaround suggestions?

Comment: You can try using a `FileGroupDescriptor`, the sample source code can be found in the  [Outlook Drag and Drop in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C) article.